# How to change the CRS for a Leaflet map at runtime?

Tags: leaflet

I have different layers with different CRS requirements. Since you cannot set CRS per-layer, but only per-map, I need to change the CRS for my map at runtime, depending on which layer is selected. How do I do this in Leaflet?

Answer (score 3):

The current version of Leaflet (1.3.x) does **not** have the feature to change the map's CRS at runtime. It's simply not possible.

Possible alternatives are: reprojecting your data so all your layers use the same CRS; or removing all layers from the map, destroying the map, creating a new instance of the map, and adding all layers back.